# Function to Determine if Nat is Divisible by 5 at Compile-Time

Tags: idris

Using [Cactus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477476/cactus)'s helpful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36465477/409976), I tried to write a function that, given a `Nat`, will return that `Nat` if it's divisible by `5`.

```
onlyModBy5Helper : (n : Nat) -> (k : Nat ** k `mod` 5 = 0) -> Nat
onlyModBy5Helper n k = n
```

And then the primary function:

```
onlyModBy5 : Nat
onlyModBy5 = onlyModBy5Helper 10 (10 ** Refl)
```

However, that failed with a compile-time error:

```
When checking right hand side of onlyModBy5 with expected type
        Nat
When checking argument pf to constructor Builtins.MkDPair:
        Type mismatch between
                0 = 0 (Type of Refl)
        and
                (\k =>
                   Prelude.Nat.Nat implementation of Prelude.Interfaces.Integral, method mod k
                                                                                             5 =
                   0) 10 (Expected type)

        Specifically:
                Type mismatch between
                        0
                and
                        Prelude.Nat.Nat implementation of Prelude.Interfaces.Integral, method mod 10
                                                                                                  5
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This case it is a bit odd: the `Integral` implementation of `Nat` is:

```
partial
Integral Nat where
  div = divNat
  mod = modNat
```

And if you use `modNat` instead of `mod` in your type signature, it works. The type unifier is still having some issues. I guess it does not resolve further, because it sees the implementation as partial and not as total.

However, your `onlyModBy5Helper` isn't exactly doing what you try to achieve, as `onlyModBy5Helper 4 (10 ** Refl)` would return `4`, as `n` and `k` of the dependent pair don't need to be the same value. This function, that takes a `n : Nat` and a proof for the `n`, is probably what you want:

```
onlyModBy5Helper : (n : Nat) -> n `modNat` 5 = 0 -> Nat
onlyModBy5Helper n prf = n
```

Note that this resembles a dependent pair, and you could (but shouldn't, as it adds unneeded abstraction), write the function as:

```
onlyModBy5Helper : (n : Nat ** n `modNat` 5 = 0) -> Nat
onlyModBy5Helper pair = fst pair
```

Comment: How can I call your `onlyModBy5Helper : (n : Nat) -> n 'mod' Nat 5 = 0 -> Nat` version on the REPL? I tried `> onlyModBy5HelperMod 1`, but got `onlyModBy5HelperMod 1 : (1 = 0) -> Nat` output.

Comment: In that case, `onlyModBy5HelperMod 1` has type ```1 `modNat` 5 = 0 -> Nat```, so you need to apply it on one more argument: a proof that ```1 `modNat` 5``` equals 0. Since it equals 1, you will not be able to provide that argument.

Comment: Thank you, Cactus and Xash. I decided to post a follow-up rather than ask in the comments - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539019/helper-function-to-determine-if-nat-mod-5-0.

Comment: Could you provide more insight as to when a dependent pair is appropriate versus it being an `unneeded abstraction`? This [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/idris-lang/C5fk6iznX7I) made me think of this SO question.