# Helper Function to Determine if Nat `mod` 5 == 0

Tags: idris

[Xash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5786950/xash) provided me with a helpful answer on [Function to Determine if Nat is Divisible by 5 at Compile-Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36531852/function-to-determine-if-nat-is-divisible-by-5-at-compile-time) (that I re-named from my original long name):

```
onlyModBy5 : (n : Nat) -> n `modNat` 5 = 0 -> Nat
onlyModBy5 n prf = n
```

A previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36465477/409976) educated me how to run it on the REPL using the `Refl` argument:

```
-- 5 % 5 == 0, so it should compile
*Test> onlyModBy5 5 Refl
5 : Nat 

-- 7 % 5 == 2, so it should not compile
*Test> onlyModBy5 7 Refl
(input):1:12:When checking an application of function Main.onlyModBy5:
        Type mismatch between
                x = x (Type of Refl)
        and
                modNat 7 5 = 0 (Expected type)

        Specifically:
                Type mismatch between
                        2
                and
                        0
```

Then, I tried to define a helper function that would provide the second `prf` (proof) argument for conciseness. In other words, I'd prefer the caller of this function to not have to provide the `Refl` argument.

```
onlyModBy5Short : (n : Nat) -> Nat
onlyModBy5Short n = onlyModBy5 n Refl
```

But, it does not compile:

```
When checking right hand side of onlyModBy5Short with expected type
        Nat

When checking an application of function Main.onlyModBy5:
        Type mismatch between
                0 = 0 (Type of Refl)
        and
                modNat n 5 = 0 (Expected type)

        Specifically:
                Type mismatch between
                        0
                and
                        Prelude.Nat.modNatNZ, mod' n 4 SIsNotZ n n 4
Holes: Main.onlyModBy5Short
```

How, if possible, can this function be written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `onlyModBy5`'s second argument an [`auto` argument](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/miscellany.html#auto-implicit-arguments):

```
onlyModBy5 : (n : Nat) -> {auto prf : n `modNat` 5 = 0} -> Nat
onlyModBy5 n = n
```

This works because for a given literal value of `n`, `` n `modNat` 5 `` can always be reduced, and so `` n `modNat` 5 = 0 `` will always reduce to `0 = 0` (in which case the constructor `Refl` has the right type) unless `n` is truly not divisible by 5.

Indeed, this will allow you to typecheck

```
foo : Nat
foo = onlyModBy5 25
```

but reject

```
bar : Nat
bar = onlyModBy5 4
```

Comment: Thank you, Cactus. I actually tried to apply this function to another question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36562497/determine-if-sum-of-vect-n-nats-evenly-divides-5.