# Auto implicit arg stops working when type is given a name

Tags: idris, leaky-abstraction

While writing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36539124/477476), I noticed that while this works as expected:

```
onlyModBy5 : (n : Nat) -> {auto prf : n `modNat` 5 = 0} -> Nat
onlyModBy5 n = n

foo : Nat
foo = onlyModBy5 25
```

but as soon as I give a name to the property it stops working:

```
Divides : Nat -> Nat -> Type
Divides n k = k `modNat` n = 0

onlyModBy5 : (n : Nat) -> {auto prf : 5 `Divides` n} -> Nat
onlyModBy5 n = n

foo : Nat
foo = onlyModBy5 25
```

now filling the `auto` arg fails with

```
Can't find a value of type 
        Divides 5 25
```

Why is Idris unable to see through `Divides`'s definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the reason, but modNat is not total. That would be a good reason to trip idris.

```
divides : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
divides n k = n `modNat` k

onlyModBy5 : (n : Nat) -> {auto prf : n `divides` 5  = 0 } -> Nat
onlyModBy5 n = n

foo : Nat
foo = onlyModBy5 25
```

For some reason this already fails as well (just indirecting once from the original version).