# Determine if Sum of Vect n Nat's Evenly Divides 5?

Tags: idris

[Cactus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477476/cactus) demonstrated how to address my question: [Helper Function to Determine if Nat `mod` 5 == 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36539019/409976).

He wrote:

```
onlyModBy5 : (n : Nat) -> {auto prf : n `modNat` 5 = 0} -> Nat
onlyModBy5 n = n
```

Then, I attempted to use that function to apply `onlyModBy5` to the sum of a `Vect n Nat`'s.

```
foo : (n : Nat) -> Vect n Nat -> Nat
foo n xs = onlyModBy5 $ sum xs
```

But I got this compile-time error:

```
When checking right hand side of foo with expected type
        Nat

When checking argument prf to function Main.onlyModBy5:
        Can't find a value of type 
                Prelude.Nat.modNatNZ, mod' (foldrImpl (\meth =>
                                                         \meth =>
                                                           plus meth meth)
                                                      0
                                                      id
                                                      xs)
                                           4
                                           SIsNotZ
                                           (foldrImpl (\meth =>
                                                         \meth =>
                                                           plus meth meth)
                                                      0
                                                      id
                                                      xs)
                                           (foldrImpl (\meth =>
                                                         \meth =>
                                                           plus meth meth)
                                                      0
                                                      id
                                                      xs)
                                           4 =
                0
Holes: Main.foo
```

How can I use the above `onlyModBy5` function with `foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve. `foo : (n : Nat) -> Vect n Nat -> Nat` says that you can apply any `Nat` to `foo`, and any `Vect` of `Nat` (if the `Vect` is of size `n`) and `foo` will return a `Nat`.

First off, you don't need the explicit `(n : Nat)` argument. If you write just `foo : Vect n Nat -> Nat`, Idris would turn `n` internally into an implicit argument: `foo : {n : Nat} -> Vect n Nat -> Nat`.

In the arguments is nothing about the elements of the `Vect`, and therefor nothing about the `sum` of it. You could apply `[1,2,2]` as well `[1,1]`, whereas the latter doesn't have a proof of `prf : (sum [1,1])` `` `modNat` ``  `5 == 0)`, so obviously you can't apply the sum to `onlyModBy5`.

You could either demand a proof of this as an argument as before:

```
bar : (xs : Vect n Nat) -> {auto prf : (sum xs) `modNat` 5 = 0} -> Nat
bar xs = onlyModBy5 (sum xs)
```

Or let it decide based on the sum:

```
foo : Vect n Nat -> Maybe Nat
foo xs = foo' (sum xs)
  where
    foo' : Nat -> Maybe Nat
    foo' k with (decEq (k `modNat` 5) 0)
      | Yes prf = Just (onlyModBy5 k {prf})
      | No _ = Nothing
```

`decEq` decides whether two values are propositionally equal (in this case, if they are the same `Nat`), and either returns `Yes` with a `(prf : n` `` `modNat` `` `5 = 0)` that they are equal, or `No` with a proof that they aren't equal. This proof can be then given to `onlyModBy5` with `{prf}`. This extends to `{prf=prf}`, which gives the implicit argument the proof of `Yes`, as both are named `prf`.

Comment: I think you could improve `foo` slightly by explicitly passing `prf` to `onlyModBy5 k` to emphasize the fact that that is where the proof is coming from now.