# Determine if `Nat mod 5 = 0` at Compile-Time in Scala

Tags: scala, shapeless, idris

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36539124/409976) demonstrates how to write a function, in Idris, to determine if a `Nat mod 5 = 0` at compile-time:

```
onlyModBy5 : (n : Nat) -> {auto prf : n `modNat` 5 = 0} -> Nat
onlyModBy5 n = n
```

Tests:

```
*Test> onlyModBy5 5
5 : Nat
*Test> onlyModBy5 10
10 : Nat
*Test> onlyModBy5 11
(input):1:12:When checking argument prf to function Main.onlyModBy5:
        Can't find a value of type 
                1 = 0
```

How can such a function be written in Scala (I'm assuming with `shapeless`)?

Answer (score 2):

Provide a proof (value) that 0 is 0 mod 5, then provide proof that (N + 5) mod 5 is 0 given proof the N mod 5 is 0:

https://gist.github.com/stew/4074742#file-fizzbuzz-scala-L81-L90

Answer (score 2):

With Shapeless it is pretty straightforward.

```
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_77).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import shapeless._
import shapeless._

scala> import ops.nat._
import ops.nat._

scala> type _5 = Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[_0]]]]]
defined type alias _5

scala> def onlyModBy5(n: Nat)(implicit ev: Mod.Aux[n.N, _5, _0], toInt: ToInt[n.N]) = toInt()
onlyModBy5: (n: shapeless.Nat)(implicit ev: shapeless.ops.nat.Mod.Aux[n.N,_5,shapeless._0], implicit toInt: shapeless.ops.nat.ToInt[n.N])Int

scala> onlyModBy5(0)
res0: Int = 0

scala> onlyModBy5(25)
res1: Int = 25

scala> onlyModBy5(47)
<console>:20: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: shapeless.ops.nat.Mod.Aux[nat_$macro$6.N,_5,shapeless._0]
       onlyModBy5(47)
                 ^
```

Integers get converted to a `Nat` by some macro, so they have to be literals and can't get too big without the compiler blowing up. The `ToInt` typeclass is used for converting the `Nat` back to an `Int`.